How can I run a function alongside an async one?
I want to kick off an async task but then have another function run that shows some animation.
I can't do
const = async myFunc => {
 // await asyncFunc()
 // await animateFunc()
}

as it won't get to animateFunc until asyncFunc has resolved
I'm not sure I can wait on promises to resolve iether as animateFunc is a continuous cyclical for loop that I run
I also want to try and avoid state with useEffect as that feels more like an anti pattern. I would like to call them both onClick and then break from the for loop once the async one resolves. what are my options here?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

didn't realise each promise in promise.all could be done like that, should have read docs more. thanks!

although i'm not sure the promise is resolving now

@mousetail'he-him' how do you resolve a continious for loop?

I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe post a new question with a minimal example of a continuous for loop and promises that explains exactly what you want and what you have and the difference between them

@mousetail'he-him' this is my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79203348/react-context-not-updating-value

At the risk of stating the obvious, if you don't want to wait for a function to complete you can also just not await
